# NEST: Elastic Search Performance Problem Because Of Empty Search

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

Using Elastic "number": "6.3.1"
"lucene_version": "7.3.1"
NEST: 6.1.0

Trying to translate the below search. Essentially message1, message2 can have empty string values. if search1Value or search2Value is empty string, i don't want any records returned for that part of the OR condition where there is an empty string.

This piece is part of a much large Search with other criteria... BUT this piece is causing the Query to ES to be extremely SLOW.  I create RAW fields in addition to the original fields when creating the index just to be able to search on NOT EMPTY.  Nothing else i had tried allowed me to do that search correctly.  IS there a different way to do this?  As mentioned the performance of the query is Terrible. Over 2secs.  The index in question have around 600k documents.   The logic DOES work though.  It does return the correct documents.

Thank you in advance for any assistance!!

```
message1 != "" and message1.StartsWith(search1Value)
OR 
message2 != "" and message2.StartsWith(search2Value)
```

so if example of available docs in index...

```
id, message1, message2
1, "", "abc"
2, "", ""
3, "def", ""
4, "", "ghi"
```

if searchValue1 is empty string, and searchValue2 is abc i want to get back, only record 1. Not record 1, 2, and 4.

in order to properly search on this condition an index was setup as such:

```
public class MessageSearch() {
       public string Message1 {get; set;}
       public string Message2 {get; set;}
    }

public class MessageModelIndex() {
   public string Message1 {get; set;} = ""
   public string Message2 {get; set;} = ""
}


public override CreateIndexDescriptor DefineIndex(string indexName)
        {
            return new CreateIndexDescriptor(indexName).Settings(s => s
                .NumberOfShards(2)                    
                .Mappings(ms => ms
                    .Map<MessageModelIndex>(m => m
                        .Properties(p => p                                
                            .Text(s => s
                                .Name(x => x.Message1)
                                .Fields(ff => ff
                                    .Text(tt => tt
                                        .Name("raw")
                                    )
                                    .Keyword(k => k
                                        .Name("keyword")
                                        .IgnoreAbove(1)
                                    )
                                )
                            )
                            .Text(s => s
                                .Name(x => x.Message2)
                                .Fields(ff => ff
                                    .Text(tt => tt
                                        .Name("raw")
                                    )
                                    .Keyword(k => k
                                        .Name("keyword")
                                        .IgnoreAbove(1)
                                    )
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    ));
        }
```

The following Search is used to get these values:

```
public void PerformSearch(MessageSearch search) {
                var result = _client.Search<MessageModelIndex>(x => x
               .Index("MessageTest")
               .Size(1000)
               .Query(q => q
                        .Bool(b => b
                                .Must(bm => bm
                                    .Bool(bb => bb
                                        .Should(bbs => bbs
                                            .Bool(bbb => bbb
                                                .Must(mm => mm
                                                    .Bool(bbbb => bbbb
                                                        .MustNot(bbbmn => bbbmn.Term(t => t.Verbatim().Field(f => f.Message1.Suffix("keyword")).Value(string.Empty)))
                                                    ),
                                                    mm => mm
                                                    .Bool(bbbb => bbbb
                                                        .Must(bbbmn => bbbmn.MatchPhrasePrefix(mmp => mmp.Query(search.Message1.Trim()).Field(f => f.Message1.Suffix("raw"))))
                                                    )
                                                 )
                                            ), bbs => bbs
                                            .Bool(bbb => bbb
                                                .Must(mm => mm
                                                    .Bool(bbbb => bbbb
                                                        .MustNot(bbbmn => bbbmn.Term(t => t.Verbatim().Field(f => f.Message2.Suffix("keyword")).Value(string.Empty)))
                                                    ),
                                                    mm => mm
                                                    .Bool(bbbb => bbbb
                                                        .Must(bbbmn => bbbmn.MatchPhrasePrefix(mmp => mmp.Query(search.Message2.Trim()).Field(f => f.Message2.Suffix("raw"))))
                                                    )
                                                 )
                                            )
                                        )
                                    )
                                )
                            )
               )
            );
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mapping and query look incorrect for your desired outcome. Let's break it down

> I create RAW fields in addition to the original fields when creating the index just to be able to search on NOT EMPTY. Nothing else i had tried allowed me to do that search correctly. IS there a different way to do this?

#### The mapping

As an example, the mapping you have

```cs
.Text(s => s
    .Name(x => x.Message1)
    .Fields(ff => ff
        .Text(tt => tt
            .Name("raw")
        )
        .Keyword(k => k
            .Name("keyword")
            .IgnoreAbove(1)
        )
    )
)
```

The `"raw"` field is superfluous as it is the same as the containing `text` data type mapping.

The `"keyword"` multi-field will index single character strings or less for `Message1`. Here, I think you want `.IgnoreAbove(0)` if the intention is to use this multi-field to be able to search for documents that have an empty string for `Message1`. I would question however if it is actually valuable to be able to search on documents with empty `Message1`; you'd be able to determine documents that have a value (even empty string) with an `exists` query, and if you did want to search on documents with empty messages, you could do so with a script query.

Ultimately, I guess if it is common to be able to search on empty messages, then having this `"keyword"` multi-field would be useful; I'd be inclined to name it `"empty"` though instead, to better match intent.

#### The search request

> `.Index("MessageTest")`

index name must be lowercase to be valid.

> ```
> .Bool(b => b
>         .Must(bm => bm
>             .Bool(bb => bb
>                 .Should(bbs => bbs
> ```

The outer `bool` query `must` clause is not needed; the `should` clauses can be moved out and  defined on the outer `bool` query.

> ```
> .Bool(bbb => bbb
>     .Must(mm => mm
>         .Bool(bbbb => bbbb
>             .MustNot(bbbmn => bbbmn.Term(t => t.Verbatim().Field(f => f.Message1.Suffix("keyword")).Value(string.Empty)))
>         ),
>         mm => mm
>         .Bool(bbbb => bbbb
>             .Must(bbbmn => bbbmn.MatchPhrasePrefix(mmp => mmp.Query(search.Message1.Trim()).Field(f => f.Message1.Suffix("raw"))))
>         )
>      )
> )
> ```

The `term` query in the `must_not` clause looks superfluous to me, because an empty string input for the `match_phrase_prefix` query will not match any documents. You can see this for yourself if you indexed the following documents

```
var bulkResponse = client.Bulk(b => b
    .IndexMany(new [] 
    {
        new MessageModelIndex { Id = 1, Message1 = "", Message2 = "abc" },
        new MessageModelIndex { Id = 2, Message1 = "", Message2 = "" },
        new MessageModelIndex { Id = 3, Message1 = "def", Message2 = "" },
        new MessageModelIndex { Id = 4, Message1 = "", Message2 = "ghi" },
    })
    .Refresh(Refresh.WaitFor)
);
```

and then run the search

```
var emptyStringInputResponse = client.Search<MessageModelIndex>(x => x
    .Index(defaultIndex)
    .Query(q => q
        .MatchPhrasePrefix(t => t
            .Verbatim()
            .Field(f => f.Message1)
            .Query("")
        )
    )
);
```

No documents are returned. This is because of analysis on the `Message1` field at index time and input targeting that field at query time.

Also note that `.Verbatim()` needs to be used here because NEST has a concept known as *conditionless* queries: if a query is determined to be conditionless, then it is not included in the serialized request JSON. For a `MatchPhrasePrefix` query, a null or empty string query input makes the query *conditionless*. Using `.Verbatim()` overrides this *conditionless* behaviour, forcing NEST to serialize the query as is.

The query can be simplified down to

```
var searchResponse = client.Search<MessageModelIndex>(x => x
    .Index(defaultIndex)
    .Size(1000)
    .Query(q => q
        .Bool(bb => bb
            .Should(bbs => bbs
                .MatchPhrasePrefix(mmp => mmp
                    .Query(search.Message1.Trim())
                    .Field(f => f.Message1)
                ), bbs => bbs
                .MatchPhrasePrefix(mmp => mmp
                    .Query(search.Message2.Trim())
                    .Field(f => f.Message2)
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

which can be further simplified with [operator overloading on queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/bool-queries.html) to

```
var searchResponse = client.Search<MessageModelIndex>(x => x
    .Index(defaultIndex)
    .Size(1000)
    .Query(q => q
        .MatchPhrasePrefix(mmp => mmp
                .Query(search.Message1.Trim())
                .Field(f => f.Message1)
            ) || q
        .MatchPhrasePrefix(mmp => mmp
            .Query(search.Message2.Trim())
            .Field(f => f.Message2)
        )
    )
);
```

which returns only document with id 1 for searchValue1 `""`, and searchValue2 `"abc"`.

Here's a complete example

```
private static void Main()
{
    var defaultIndex = "message-test";
    var pool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"));

    var settings = new ConnectionSettings(pool)
        .DefaultIndex(defaultIndex);

    var client = new ElasticClient(settings);

    if (client.IndexExists(defaultIndex).Exists)
        client.DeleteIndex(defaultIndex);

    client.CreateIndex(defaultIndex, c => c
        .Mappings(m => m
            .Map<MessageModelIndex>(mm => mm
               .Properties(p => p
                    .Text(s => s
                        .Name(x => x.Message1)
                        .Fields(ff => ff
                            .Keyword(k => k
                                .Name("keyword")
                                .IgnoreAbove(0)
                            )
                        )
                    )
                    .Text(s => s
                        .Name(x => x.Message2)
                        .Fields(ff => ff
                            .Keyword(k => k
                                .Name("keyword")
                                .IgnoreAbove(0)
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    );

    var bulkResponse = client.Bulk(b => b
        .IndexMany(new [] 
        {
            new MessageModelIndex { Id = 1, Message1 = "", Message2 = "abc" },
            new MessageModelIndex { Id = 2, Message1 = "", Message2 = "" },
            new MessageModelIndex { Id = 3, Message1 = "def", Message2 = "" },
            new MessageModelIndex { Id = 4, Message1 = "", Message2 = "ghi" },
        })
        .Refresh(Refresh.WaitFor)
    );

    var search = new MessageSearch
    {
        Message1 = "",
        Message2 = "abc"
    };

    var searchResponse = client.Search<MessageModelIndex>(x => x
        .Index(defaultIndex)
        .Size(1000)
        .Query(q => q
            .MatchPhrasePrefix(mmp => mmp
                    .Query(search.Message1.Trim())
                    .Field(f => f.Message1)
                ) || q
            .MatchPhrasePrefix(mmp => mmp
                .Query(search.Message2.Trim())
                .Field(f => f.Message2)
            )
        )
    );
}

public class MessageSearch 
{
    public string Message1 { get; set; }
    public string Message2 { get; set; }
}

public class MessageModelIndex 
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Message1 { get; set; } = "";
   public string Message2 { get; set; } = "";
}
```

Comment: Thanks Russ for the analysis.  The outer 'bool' query 'must' clause is not needed... right, i forgot to remove it for this break down example.. recall i mentioned there is a bunch of other parts the to FULL query that i removed, because this part was the problem. I will try out these suggestions and see if it helps. Thx for your time looking at this.

Comment: So several questions.  1. Why didn't you need to use Verbatim like you mentioned in your final query example. and why don't you actually need to specify must not empty  2. Why don't we need to specify the suffix of the field that we searching on 'keyword'? 3. Is it implied that it also searches the original text field, in addition to the keyword multifield?   4. I tried to use exists query but that always returned me the wrong answer. In other words, it just didn't work. It seemed like it was just being ignored

Comment: 5. I only have what you wrote in your final example hitting the 600k records, and it still takes 2sec to return an answer.  So the performance didn't change at all.

Comment: 1. You don't need `.Verbatim()` on `MatchPhrasePrefix` because (a) an empty string input will trigger conditionless behaviour so the query will not be serialized as part of JSON request and (b) using `.Verbatim()` and sending an empty string will not match anything on an analyzed field anyway. 2. We don't specify the suffix as we don't want to search on the `"keyword"` multi-field, only on the `text` field, which has been analyzed. 3. No, this is not implied, it will only search the `text` field, we have no need to search the `keyword` field as it is only an indicator in this case that....

Comment: ...the document field was empty at index time. As I said in the answer, there may be limited value in having this multi-field, unless searching for empty string messages is commonplace. 4. `exists` query will return all documents that have a value for a field. A value in this case is any non-null string. 5. Performance is going to depend on a heap of factors, including hardware, load, analysis, etc. I would evaluate the query in the Search Profiler UI: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.5/_tune_your_queries_with_the_profile_api.html.

Comment: I would also evaluate if `MatchPhrasePrefix` is the right query to use in this case. A prefix matches on the last term can be relatively expensive. You may want to look at Completion Suggester for _fast search as you type_, or analyzing input using edge NGrams. See the important admonition on: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query-phrase-prefix.html

Comment: 1. I thought the whole point of using Verbatim was because of the need to send in an empty string.  2-3. If we not searching on the 'keyword' field why do we still need it in the index creation. I don't see how that multi-field is used in other words. 4 i think i had tried the must not exists and it didn't do what i expected.  5. i tried multiple shards didn't make a difference.   not including this query, but including terms search on something else worked much faster.. in the 100ms timing. just seems like something is wrong.

Comment: I have answered your questions above, and provided a complete example to demonstrate. Have you tried running it?

Comment: Thank you very much for your time answering this, and putting together a nice sample.  I now get a timing of 70ms.  Which is much better.  i still don't understand why .Keyword(k => k .Name("keyword").IgnoreAbove(0))  is needed then if we're not using the multifield in the query.